# How to take the frobenius norm of Jacobian of inner product of these two q dimensional vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, jacobian, frobenius-method

$$
\begin{array}{l}
B_1 \cdot s=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1d_1} \\
\vdots & \cdots & & \vdots \\
b_{q_1 1} & \cdots    & b_{q_1 d_1}
\end{array}\right]_{q_1 \times d_1} \cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}
s_1 \\
s_2 \\
s_3 \\
s_{d_1}
\end{array}\right]_{d_1 \times 1} \\
=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} s_1+b_{12} s_2+\cdots b_{1 d_1} s_{d_1} \\
\vdots \\
b_{q_1 1} s_1 & \cdots & b_{q_1 d_1} s_{d_1}
\end{array}\right]_{q_1 \times 1} \\
\sigma\left(B_1 \cdot s\right)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\sigma\left(b_{11} s_1+\cdots b_{1 d_1} s_{d_1}\right) \\
\vdots \\
\sigma\left(b_{q_1} s_1+\cdots b_{q_1 d_1} s_{d_1}\right)
\end{array}\right]_{q_1 \times 1} \\
=\left[\begin{array}{c}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\vdots \\
u_{q_1}
\end{array}\right]_{q_1 \times 1} \\
\end{array}
$$
Following the same calculation for $\sigma\left(T_1 p\right)$ $=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\sigma\left(t_{11} p_1+\cdots \cdot t_{1 d_2} p_{d_2}\right) \\ \vdots \\ \sigma\left(t_{q_2 1} p_1+\cdots \cdot t_{q_2 d_2} p_{d_2}\right)\end{array}\right]$ $=\left[\begin{array}{c}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_{q_2}\end{array}\right]_{q_2 \times 1}$

$h=\left\langle\sigma\left(B_1 \cdot s\right), \sigma\left(T_1 \cdot p\right)\right\rangle$

How to get $h$ ? Here $\sigma$ = sigmoid

**Edit**

Here $q_1 = q_2 = q$ and ,**$d$ = 2**

I particularly [interested to implement this calculation for my $h(s,p)$](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00440-014-0579-3.pdf) . But getting no clue :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't. Or, rather, you can't assuming that $q_1\ne q_2$ and assuming that your interpretation of the question is correct in the first place. Without more context, I cannot say more.

Comment: It is not any assumption. I have just given this calculation part here. In original context q1≠q2 always

Comment: As I said, there isn't enough context here. It seems to me that, whatever the mistake is, it's been made before you even got to this step.

Comment: Why are you thinking so? I have double checked, nothing I got wrong in the prev steps

Comment: What you are asking is akin to asking how to add $2 m$ to $3 kg$. It cannot be done, and you need to understand how come that the one value you need to add is in metres and the other in kilograms. Speaking figuratively, of course.

Comment: Hi @StinkingBishop I have edited now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141062/discussion-between-nets-and-stinking-bishop).

Comment: Um... If $q_1=q_2$ then ... there is no problem!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141063/discussion-between-nets-and-stinking-bishop).

Answer (score -1):

For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\D{{\rm Diag}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
z &= B_1s,\qquad e=\s(z),\qquad E=\D(e) \\
y &= T_1p,\qquad f=\s(y),\qquad F=\D(f) \\
}$$
The derivative of the [logistic sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative) is well known
$$\eqalign{
de &= \left(E-E^2\right)dz \\
df &= \left(F-F^2\right)dy 
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
}$$
Now calculate the derivative of the $h$-function wrt some independent $x$ variable
$$\eqalign{
h &= e^Tf \\
dh &= e^Tdf \;+\; f^Tde \\
 &= e^T\left(F-F^2\right)dy \;+\; f^T\left(E-E^2\right)dz \\
 &= e^T\left(F-F^2\right)\g{y}{x}\:dx \;+\; f^T\left(E-E^2\right)\g{z}{x}\:dx \\
J = \g{h}{x}
 &= e^T\left(F-F^2\right)\g{y}{x} \;+\; f^T\left(E-E^2\right)\g{z}{x} \\
}$$
The norm of $J$ can be calculated as
$$\|J\|_F^2 = {\rm Trace}\left(J^TJ\right)$$

### Update

The independent variable $x$ was not specified in the question, but assuming $\,x=s$
$$\eqalign{
\g{z}{x} = \g{(B_1s)}{s} = B_1,\qquad
 \g{y}{x} = \g{(T_1p)}{s} = 0\; \\
}$$
Conversely, assuming $\,x=p\;$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\g{z}{x} = \g{(B_1s)}{p} = 0,\qquad
\;\; \g{y}{x} = \g{(T_1p)}{p} = T_1 \\
}$$

Comment: but the derivative of the h should b wrt s and p. not wrt an arbitrary x. Also why are you taking diag(e) only

Comment: The reason for using diagonal matrices is to avoid introducing Hadamard products.

Comment: why are you taking partials on z and y. It should be on h(s,p). and there must be three partials if I am not wrong. del/del s , del/ del p , del/ del sp  ... Jacobian on h(s,p) will be a matrix containing these partials